# Handling update models and synchronizes with database in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I had Two simple questions

- It's possible to update a data base without loosing all the records only in the case when i added a new table or column that doesn't make a conflict with the existing Data??.
- How can I stop from be created Entities name with the superlative "Set" at the end of the name of the new entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Entity Framework Migrations:
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-released.aspx
>
> 2) It is done by convention and it is the recommended way unless you
>   have a real reason to leave the path of conventions...